# How to load the current content with jQuery Address plugin on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, jquery-address

I am not very familiar with the [JQuery Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/), but i came up with this code, and its working great, except in this situation: When i click on the "nav a", the url is changed and the content is also changed, but when i am reload the page, the plugin is not triggered by default.

```
$("#player aside nav a").address(function(event, hash) {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.ajax_container').hide().removeClass('current');
    $('#player aside nav a').removeClass('active');
    $('#'+rel).show().addClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    return $(this).attr('href').replace(/^#/, '');  
});
```

Any idea, how can i trigger this function on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at [$.address.externalChange(fn)](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/#api-reference). When I click the back this event will fire and I believe it gives you the hash value.

Comment: `$.address.externalChange(function(event) { $('a[href='+event.value+']').trigger('click'); });` This will do the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just trigger the click event of that link.  Put it in a "dom ready" function:

```
$(function() {
   $("#player aside nav a").click();
});
```

Comment: Great idea, but sadly, this is not good for me. I posted in my question a lot simpler code, the actual selector is this: $("#player aside nav a,#player aside .lejatszolistaim a.simple_playlist_link, #artists a"), so its hard to implement the click() function on page load.

Comment: I still think my suggestion will work if you in fact need to simply mimic the behavior of clicking a link on page load.